# gives many errors when using expdp command

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, expdp, oracle-dump

expdp is giving the following errors.

```
C:\db>expdp SYSTEM/xxx@orcl directory=dump_dir dumpfile=anew.dmp log=export.log schemas=anew

Export: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Qua Fev 17 17:09:00 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31637: cannot create job SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 for user SYSTEM
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT_INT", line 798
ORA-39244: Event to disable dropping null bit image header during relational select
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 86
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPC$QUE_INT", line 1840
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

There is no orphan jobs in my system:

```
select * from dba_datapump_jobs;
no rows selected
```

Any ideas about this error?

Answer (score 0):

The temporary table created every time a datapump is started has not been automatically dropped.

- Solution 1: drop table sys.job_name with sys rights
- Solution 2: use a **.par** file and put entries like below (change to suit your job):

```
DIRECTORY=dump_dir
DUMPFILE=anew.dmp
LOGFILE=export.log
PARALLEL=16
SCHEMAS=anew
JOB_NAME=new_expdp  <----- this has to change
```

Comment: For solution 1(dropt table SYS.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01;) I received "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist". Solution 2 didn´t help, I tried a brand new job_name but the error remains the same.

Comment: Change the filename from "anew.dmp" to anything else (if filename exists EXPDP throw exception). Most probably SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 is in SYSTEM schema not SYS.

Comment: @SergiuVelescu I tried your suggestion, but the error remains. 
Since it is a test environment I decided to drop the oracle instance and create it again from scratch. Problem solved.